# Feign Client and name from properties

Tags: java, spring, rest, feign

I have sth like this,

```
@FeignClient(name = "${airport.service.name}")
```

And I have compilation error like,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service id not legal hostname (${airport.service.name})

The question is how can I pass hostname form `applciation.yaml` to FeignClient?

Comment: Have you added `@PropertySource("classpath:applciation.yaml")` on top of class ?

Comment: configuraiton is from spring cloud config

Comment: are you sur that your configuration contains the key ?

Comment: yeap, i found the issue.. typos..

Answer (score 20):

Though it is late, I am updating my answer since I faced this exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service id not legal hostname) while using feign client in spring cloud
The root cause is feign client **won't accept service name with under score**, Please go through the below link. To resolve this issue I renamed the service name to be used by feign client with hypen(school-service) instead of understore(school_service)

[Github link - spring-cloud-netflix - Issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1257)
[Github link - spring-cloud-netflix - commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/commit/b78242ce4f8c289a09f0b6b2821c5211e93a8921)

Comment: This was it indeed in my code as well, I think you can simply resolve this question with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `feign.client.config.airport-service.name`,and configure in the property or yml.
see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-openfeign.adoc

Answer (score 0):

You can specify url parameter, rather than name parameter:

```
@FeignClient(name = "${airport.service.name}", url = "${airport.service.url}")
```

and if you need to make path configurable, you can use something like

```
 @RequestMapping(
            path = "${airport.service.path}"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolving the Feign clients is one of the first things does during startup. Having this Problem can also relate to a misconfiguration. Ensure that your Application can find/detect/read the configuration file (application.yml/bootstrap.yml).

Answer (score 0):

Use **value** property instead of **name** and it will work fine.
Also check how to configure using application.yml in below code snippet

application.yml-->

```
airport:
  service:
    name: AIRPORT-SERVICE
```

Feign client interface-->

```
@FeignClient(value="${airport.service.name}")
```