# Customise docker service name created using docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, docker-stack

We are using docker stack deploy to create or update the docker services, with this approach the service name is defined as "StackName_ServiceName". Can we have '-' instead of using '_' for the service name?

This is required as one of our docker services fails to start as it considers underscore to be an illegal character in the service name.

Similar issue [Feign Client and name from properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230475/feign-client-and-name-from-properties)

Comment: can you provide link to the compose file ?

Comment: Probably these links might help you 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546497/how-to-change-the-service-name-generated-by-docker-stack-in-docker-compose 2. https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/2885

Comment: @ravikt To resolve this issue, we need to use service create command instead of docker stack deploy.

Comment: did you try `docker service create` with `--name` flag ?

Comment: Yes, docker service creates works, can we execute service create command with docker-compose yaml file.

Comment: Yes, you need `Docker Compose` for that. You may want to read this  link https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/. Its a short but helpful guideline.